# Const Iterator Reference Iterator Error

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, std

```
class Train_model
{
std::vector<Train *> trains_;
public:
const std::vector<Train *>& Trains() const { return trains_; }; // return read_only reference
}

// in a function that uses Train_model
const std::vector<Train *> trains = train_model->Trains();
for (std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator *it = trains.begin(); it != trains.end(); ++it)
{

}
```

The error is:

> /Users/user/Desktop/TEO/TEO/gurobi_model.cpp:16:48: No viable
>   conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__normal_iterator') to '`std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator *`' (aka
>   '`__normal_iterator<const_pointer, vector_type> *`')

I want to loop over all entries in the vector, but the iterator is broken? How can I fix this?

Comment: `std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator *it` should be `std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator it`; drop the `*`.

Comment: @Niall If it's a typo probably best not to respond at all? Otherwise you encourage more typo questions... "Answer section or not at all"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo;

```
std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator *it
```

Should be

```
std::vector<Train *>::const_iterator it
//                                   ^^ drop the *
```

Iterators already behave as pointers and do not need the indirection.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a pointer to an iterator, as the other says:

```
std::vector< Train* >::const_iterator it;
```

But there's one more thing, which I think should be mentioned. If you write the line below than you should use `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead of the non-c versions:

```
for ( std::vector< Train* >::const_iterator it = trains.cbegin(); it != trains.cend(); ++it )
{
    // ...
}
```